# How to install Win-10 on a M/C that came with Win-11

Tags: drivers

I got a brand new Dell Workstation 3660 with following specs.

i-7 12700
2 NVIDIA T-600 Cards To Run 8 Monitors
Win-11 Pro
Three M.2 NVMe 512GB where Win-11 is on one of them
Three 4TB SATA 5400 rpm HDD
Eight 24 inch Monitors ( 1920 x 1200 ) Resolution

I am running into lots of issues starting from day one when Dell guy installed the system & for last 3 weeks Dell engineers have worked on it online & in person & reinstalling Win-11 with no success even with a small issue like Microphone not working & Dell is not helping or responding to my emails. So I want to try something different.

Remove the NVMe that has Win-11.

Put the blank NVMe in that slot & Fresh Install Win-10 on it.

Will that work or am I going to create more problems ? Meaning which drivers will I have to change & where can I find some of those ? ( Graphics I can from NVIDIA ) but what about BIOS OR Chipset or Sound ( Realtek ) I can't install them from Dell because I got M/C with Windows-11.

I read up on How to download Win-10 iso from MS & create a bootable USB pen drive with Rufus. Would I need a key for Win-10 to install it or do I get a 30 day trial

Comment: Threaten to send it back as 'not suitable for purpose'. That'll get their attention.

Answer (score 2):

> I am running into lots of issues starting from day one when Dell guy
> installed the system

Windows 11 Pro works fine and drivers work fine.  Inevitably there are updates but overall it works fine:  Microphone works, speakers work, audio works, video works, updates work.

(1) Send it back and ask for a system that works.

(2) Reinstall Windows 11 yourself, update drivers with the Dell driver updater, update Windows, and add what works.

(3) If your system has downgrade rights to Windows 10 (ask Dell), then downgrade to Windows 10.

(4) If no downgrade rights, you have to purchase Windows 10.

To repeat: Windows 11 works fine (I have been running Windows 11 since July a year ago).

Comment: Thank you. Really appreciate your tine & effort.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 11 still has many problems, as can be found on our site.
If it doesn't work for your computer model, then Windows 10 is
much more stable alternative.

You may download Windows 10 from the Microsoft page of
[Windows 10 download page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/create-an-iso-file-for-windows-10-38547366-1dcb-7afd-1726-9eb222d72705).

Select the "Create Windows 10 installation media" download, to download
the media creation tool, and use this tool to create the boot USB.
This is preferable to using a third-party tool.

You might not need to erase the current Windows 11 installation.
I haven't tried it, but the two versions are very similar, so one may
install correctly over the other.

Comment: Thank you. Really appreciate your tine & effort